# How to add code to custom field to every blog post via php?

Tags: custom-field

I have a custom field value in every post. I need a rule to automatically add code to that custom field in every blog post. How can I do this ? thanks :)

Comment: Need clarification - you are saving code (what kind?) as custom field values on every post? Do you need this done in a batch or whenever posts are edited?

Comment: the custom field display just html code, it is a value. I need to envelope it with a script in every post. It should work this way : 
- user write a post using a front end post editor, giving the custom field a value
- after post is sent, the custom field should be automatically enveloped (I guess via php) with a script that makes that field visible only for registered users. Actually I add manually the shortcodes of a content locker before and after the custom field, but I would like the procedure to be automated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `update_post_metadata` hook to edit any custom field value right before it's saved to the database. For example:

```
function update_my_post_metadata( $check, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value ) {
    if ( $meta_key === 'MY_META_KEY' ) {
        $meta_value = 'BEFORE' . $meta_value . 'AFTER';
        update_post_meta( $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
        return true;
    }
}
add_filter( 'update_post_metadata', 'update_my_post_metadata', 10, 5 );
```

In that example you would replace MY_META_KEY with your meta key, and BEFORE and AFTER with whatever arbitrary HTML or shortcode you wish to wrap the meta value in.

Alternately -- looking at the details in your comment -- if you're just trying to make it so that only registered users can see it, you can do that when you're outputting the meta value, like this:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'MY_META_KEY', true );
}
```